# Suspend background thread while working in main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I have a GUI reading / writing some data with many entries, where writing a single entry is fast but writing all entries takes long.

- Writing of *all* entries should begin concurrently in a background thread right after startup (some properties can only be shown once all entries are written).
- The user should be able to request a single read / write on the main thread without having to wait *noticably* long. I.e. the request should cause the background thread to wait after finishing its current single write
- Once the single read / write on the main thread completes, the background thread should continue where it left off before being paused.

I have a solution which is running and working as far as I can see, but this is my first concurrent C++ code and maybe "it works" isn't the best metric for correctness.

For the sake of simplified code:

- I start with some raw `data` vector and "write" consists of processing the elements in-place.
- I can ask an element in `data` if it is already processed (`is_processed(...)`)

Here is the simplified code:

```
// includes ..
using namespace std; // only to make the question less verbose
class Gui {
    vector<int> data;

    mutex data_mtx;
    condition_variable data_cv;
    atomic_bool background_blocked = false;
  
    // ...
}

Gui::Gui() {
    // some init work .. like obtaining the raw data
    thread background_worker([this]{fill_data();});
    background_worker.detach();
}

void Gui::fill_data() { // should only do processing work while main thread does not
    unique_lock data_lock(data_mtx);
    background_blocked = false;
    for(auto& entry : raw_data) {
        data_cv.wait(data_lock, [this]{return !background_blocked;});
        if(!is_processed(entry)) proccess(entry);
    }
}

int Gui::get_single_entry(int i) { // called by main thread - should respond immediately / pause background work
    background_blocked = true;
    unique_lock data_lock(data_mtx);

    auto& entry = data[i];
    if(!is_processed(entry)) process(entry);
    const auto result = entry;

    background_blocked = false;
    data_lock.unlock();
    data_cv.notify_one();

    return result;
}

// ...
```

(A non-useful but illustrative example could be raw `data` containing only even numbers, `process(..)` adding `1` to the number, and `is_processed(..)` returning true if the number is odd. The property that can only be know after processing everything could be number of primes in the processed data - e.g. `process(..)` could also increment a prime-counter)

I think I am mostly unsure about safe reading. I can't find it right now but the gcc (which I use) doc says something like "if no thread is writing to a variable, reading of the variable from any thread is safe" - I did not see it say anything about the case where only 1 thread is writing, but other threads are reading at the same time. In the latter case, I assume not only could there be race-conditions, but a write may also be half-complete and thus a read could result in garbage?

- To my understanding I need atomic for this reason, which is why I have `atomic_bool background_blocked`. Before asking this question, I actually just had non-atomic `bool background blocked` with the same code otherwise - it still ran and worked - but to my understanding I was lucky (or not unlucky) and this was wrong .. am I understanding this right?
- I cannot `background_blocked = true` inside the lock on main thread, since the background thread is running. I think, instead of atomic, I could also use a second mutex just for the `bool background_blocked`? Is `atomic_bool` the better choice here?
- Regarding the order of unlock / notify - If I read [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one) right, I have to `unlock` before `notify_one` here, otherwise notify could make the background thread try to acquire the still-locked mutex, fail, and then wait for the next notify which may never come - and only then would the main thread unlock the mutex .. correct?
- It is hard to be sure whether the code is correct or I am just not "unlucky" to get wrong results. But I think my design is correct and does what I want .. is it? I did not find more a standard / idiomatic design to solve my problem - am I overcomplicating anything / is there a better design?

Comment: This question is quite broad, so it would be helpful to reduce it to a _minimal_ example. But if all you're looking for is a synchronization primitive where the background thread is always preempted by the main thread, a [read-write lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) is a good choice. The background thread locks for reading each time it needs to process data, and the main thread for writing. The main thread thread always has priority over the background thread, in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make the code more minimal, but some of the bulleted questions may be a bit broad - I included them to illustrate my understanding - but view the main question to be whether the code correctly fulfills my need or if there is some (hard-to-spot?) error. I had not come across read-write lock in my search and it looks promising so thanks for the link!

Comment: It is almost impossible to make code reliable if one thread `wait`s on something that another thread modifies without holding the `mutex` associated with the condition variable. You do this with `background_blocked`. If it's supposed to be protected by the mutex associated with the c.v, don't modify it without holding the mutex. If it's not supposed to be protected by the mutex associated with the c.v., you can't `wait` for it.

Comment: Re, "this thread should pause _immediately_..." That's not realistic. The thread should pause _when it's safe_ (i.e., when it doesn't have any mutexes locked, and maybe when it isn't holding on to any other resources that it won't need during the pause.) The simple approach is to have it check at one or more 'safe' places in its top-level loop to see whether it still has permission to proceed, and have it hold there until `notify()`ed if it does not have permission.

Comment: @Solomon Slow immediately was a bad word choice due to my "single" writes being very fast, so I rather meant it should pause as soon as the current write is finished. Will edit the question

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I cannot set `background_blocked = true;` *after* `unique_lock data_lock(data_mtx);` in `get_single_entry(...`, because the mutex is already locked by the background thread, and making the background thread unlock it requires `background_blocked = true;` in the first place. Do I not handle this by having `atomic_bool`? Do I need a second mutex instead?

Comment: @Shiwayari Re-architect so the background thread does not hold the mutex more than necessary.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz meaning lock inside the loop instead of using cv? The loop is very tight as each entry is very fast (<1 ms, but there are 100000+). Does that much repeated lock-unlock not degrade performance? I do not want to wait longer for the background thread than I have to

Comment: @Shiwayari You have an architectural problem. You want threads to be able to wait based on the value of `background_blocked`. But for some reason, the condition variable they're waiting for is associated with a mutex doesn't protect `background_blocked`. That's a broken design and will lead to race conditions. There are lots of possible fixes, but if you have a thread that's holding a mutex for most of the time, something is very wrong. Why is that data protected by a mutex then? As you see, that makes it too hard for other threads to get to that data. Use something else. (Mutex + C.V.?)

Comment: @Shiwayari For one thing, why are you holding the lock that protects the collection of entries while you are processing each entry? Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220377/discussion-between-shiwayari-and-david-schwartz).